# MVVM - listview itemsSource binding different than binding of listview's elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have more of a question than problem.
I have my listView in XAML:

```
<ListView Margin="25,10,25,10" Name="BookListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Number: " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Button Content="Read" Visibility="Hidden" Name="ReadButton" Command="{Binding ReadCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="ReadButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And for formality my DataContext:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new BookListViewModel();
}
```

My listView itemsSource is binded to observableCollection of elements of my class called "Book" in my viewModel and everything works great (in this code snippet I deleted all code which specify looks of this window).
My problem is that each element in my list contains a button which shows up, when element is clicked. If I bind my command as I did in this code, application will expect my ReadCommand to be in Book class code, which as I always thought violate the MVVM Pattern. 
So my question is - is this solution acceptable in MVVM pattern? If no, then how can I go back from binding to observableList in listView to binding the viewModel in my button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a `ReadCommand` property in the `Book` class does not violate MVVM in any way. However, it might be more reasonable and convenient to have the `ReadCommand` in your view model. In that case, you can use `RelativeSource` to get to the ListView's DataContext, which is in fact the view model:

```
<Button Content="Read" Visibility="Hidden" Name="ReadButton"
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ReadCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
```

Comment: Ha, thanks, exactly what I wanted. It's my first project with MVVM, but I thought that I shouldn't put commands in model classes.